# cloth physics are not working properly

Tags: mesh, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

I Kind of searched on the internet but could not find a proper solution , so the cloth plane whenever I try to add a character and put collision on , the cloth does does jiggle or kind of vibrating all over it , I just want to make it straight , I trying to make a ghost simulation with cloth on but it just vibrate , any idea , thank you.

[image]

This is the blend file here for more

[image]

Comment: Is it better if you deactivate the Single Sided option of the collision object? If not, please share your file

Comment: I've tested your file, delete the Bake, deactivate the Single Sided option of the body, recalculate, it works

Comment: you are the best moonboots , much respect

Answer (score 1):

Delete the bake, deactivate the *Single Sided* option of the body, it works (don't ask me why though aha, it seems to work better without this option).

Comment: yea it worked actually , one last comment i wanted to add if i wanna make the cloth Kinda Like straight cloth like without making the cloth moving much and also without these sided zig zag lol I honestly Dont Know the right word for it but i hope you got what i mean much respect mate

Comment: add a Subdivision Surface modifier, also tight click > Shade Smooth